# keychain ssh-agent incorrect informations

Tags: linux, ssh, keychain, ssh-agent

I'm using keychain, which manages my key(s) with ssh-agent perfectly.

I want to check the state of ssh-agent on each linux host. I tried with :

```
ssh-add -l
1024 f7:51:28:ea:98:45:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX /root/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Locally, this command works and is coherent.

But with a distant SSH command, I don't know why the result is not the same.. :

```
## host1, locally
ssh-add -l
1024 f7:51:28:ea:98:45:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX /root/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

## host 2, command to host1 : 
ssh host1 "ssh-add -l"
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Maybe someone could explain me ?  It't disturbing, because I would to monitor ssh-agent states..

Thanks.

EDIT : Even with SSH Agent Forwarding enabled, the distant command returns only the local state of agent.  Other distant commands works, with or without key loaded..

```
## Host1, locally
ssh-add -l
1024 f7:51:28:ea:98:45:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX /root/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

## From Host2, locally and distant :
ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.

ssh -A host1 "ssh-add -l"
The agent has no identities.
```

Comment: if you don't have agent forwarding enabled on the connection you get that error. try with `ssh -A host1 "ssh-add -l"`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried, it seems not to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how `keychain`/`ssh-agent` work. When you log onto a system (we'll call it 'home'), it starts a program. As part of starting this program it exposes a file that `ssh-add` can connect to. When the name of this file is stored in the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable, it becomes accessible by `ssh` and by `ssh-add` when run with this enviroment variable set appropriately.

When you ssh to a remote system, if the `ForwardAgent` property is set to true in your configuration, a channel is established allowing this key information to pass from your 'home' system to the system that you've ssh'd to. In order to expose this key information, another `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is set on this remote system. So now we have:

```
# home system (host1)
host1$ ssh-add -l
1024 BLAH....
host1$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-YJNLu2LFMKbO/agent.1472
home$ ssh -A host2
host2$ ssh-add -l
1024 BLAH
host2$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-vqdu733feY/agent.23877
host2$ ssh -A host1
host1$ ssh-add -l
1024 BLAH
host1$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-fuKgOaaQ7b/agent.23951
```

so with every connection, a socket is created on the remote system to ferry the key data through the chain to the original 'home' system. So in this example:

```
ssh-agent(on host1) makes a SOCKET -> ssh(host2) [provides a SOCKET connecting back to the SOCKET on host1] -> ssh(host1) [provides a SOCKET connecting back to the socket on host2]
```

So ssh, once you connect to the remote system is providing a socket that connects back to the socket from the system that it came from.

If you log on to a system directly (e.g. logging onto host2 at the console), then there is absolutely no connection back to host1. If an agent is started on host2, then it provides it's own, private socket, that you are communicating with.

Where things can go wrong:

You've enabled agent forwarding on your connection from host1 -> host2; however the script that runs at login on host2 ignores the presence of this socket and starts it's own private agent on host2. As a result when you ask for lists of registered keys using `ssh-add -l`, it talks to the socket provided by the agent running on host2. This agent does not have access to the keys from host1 as it ignored the socket.

agent forwarding can be disabled by the sshd_config, which means that the server administrator has configured the system to prevent people forwarding their agent information into this system (if there's an AllowAgentForwarding no line in the sshd_config then this would be the case).

The first case would be when there is a badly written login script that ignores the presence of the variable - i.e. it doesn't properly detect the fact that the connection is remote and there is a socket being forwarded - this is rare, but can happen. If it does then the script would need to be rewritten to detect this case.

If the administrator of the remote system has disabled agent forwarding, then you need to ask for it to be enabled.

Comment: It's complicated, but I think I understand.. : With Keychain, one ssh connection = one new socket to open ? So with multiple connections, machines could be have a lot of process/sockets ?  I tried to enable in sshd_config `AllowAgentForwarding` but it's normal, even like that, it doesn't works if I'm connecting with local console.. ?  Right ?  THanks for your post                                               So, from one central server, do you think possible to launch `ssh hostX "check if key has been loaded" `  ??

Comment: if you're running the agent on the central server, and all the instances of ssh that launch from that server set their `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to point to this agent then every client they connect to will be able to make use of the connection back to central for the duration of the connection. Note that they only connect back to the *single running agent* via the socket in this case.

Comment: In this case, when you `ssh -A hostX` the key will be accessible through the connection back to the agent running on the central server *for this connection only* (i.e. things running within that ssh session), and won't be accessible from, for example, other local terminal windows on hostX.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.  So, because sockets are very private, I can't check if a key is loaded among all ssh-agent processes/sockets..

Comment: Keys belong to a singular ssh-agent, it exposes them via a local socket. a relay socket gets created on a remote system when you perform an ssh connection. This relay socket lasts for the duration of the connection and is usable by programs that this connection launches while the connection still exists. If you want to check if a key is loaded by a particular ssh-agent you need to access it's socket.